# Trying to run selenium - test on angular site

Tags: angularjs, selenium

I try to run a selenium test (using selenium IDE on Firefox) For an angular app.
I followed the instructions here in SO and added something like this:

```
Command=waitForElementPresent 
Target=//h3
```

But even if there are a lot of H3s generated quite quickly by the app, Selenium does not seem to be able to find any them. (it keeps waiting on the WaitForElementPresent command)

Anything else I have to do to make this work?

Comment: We need more info, website, is the website you're trying to scrape of angularjs or are you using it yourself? What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you to use protractor in addition to Selenium. Basically its a Javascript executor which can locate elements by ng tags. I tried to test an angular site with selenium only, but protractor really made my life easier!

Answer (score 0):

If there are are many H3 tags in your application , it would be a good idea to give an unique Id to tags .

like :

```
<h3 id="someUniqueId"> heading </h3>
```

which can be accessed by :

```
Command=waitForElementPresent 
Target=id=someUniqueId
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make the entire switch to Protractor but you do want to wait for Angular I recommend using [Paul Hammants ngWebDriver](https://github.com/paul-hammant/ngWebDriver) (Java).

For me the standard selenium implicit wait didn't work as our page is built asyncronously with Angular. I fixed this by writing an actions class in which I waited for Angular (using ngWebDriver's waitForAngularRequestsToFinish()) before carrying out the actions (click, fill, check etc.).